# Trailhead - Report Query

Tags: reporting, trailhead

I am trying to create this report for trailhead challenge.

1)

[image]

I am not sure how to approach this.

I even thought of using a matrix report but based on my understanding, you need to have a "row" and "col" grouping. The "col" grouping can be Close Date but I do not know what to keep for "row" grouping so I discarded the idea of using "matrix" report.

Then I chose "Summary" report and did a grouping based on "Close Date" but I am not sure how to display the sum.

2) Also how do I show another data metric for deals (the line data) ?

I know this is a bit much so I would appreciate if I can get a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: What is the link for the trailhead challenge?

Comment: [Here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000Ze7aAAC) you can find how to create the report you are asking for